# installshield 2011 downgrade

Tags: windows-installer, installshield-2011

I had generated two msi installers(installshield 2011 project): first has version 5.0.188.0 and second 5.0.190.0. At first i installed version 5.0.190.0, after that i installed version 5.0.188.0 (downgrade).

Result is (erroneous) message box: "this setup will perform upgrade. do you want to continue?". I press button "yes" and have (desired) mesage box "a later version is already installed on this machine. the setup cannot continue.".

How i can forbid first erroneous dialog?